# Check if post is liked by user. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if post was liked by a authenticated user when I display all posts of the users. This is my approach to this right now:

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $user = Auth::user();
    $liked = Post::with('user')
        ->whereHas('like', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
        })->get();
    return view('index', compact('posts', 'liked'));
}
```

And when I do this in HTML:

```
@if($liked)
    <button class="[ btn btn-primary ]">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> You like this</button>
@else
    <a href="/patinka/{{$p->id}}" type="button" class="[ btn btn-default ]">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</a>
@endif
```

I always get "You like this" even though I did not liked that post. Can someone tell me whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: coudl you try and do a `dd($liked)`so to see whats  being returned, to check if its what you expect as the result could be more than a value and an array etc so the variable $liked might be wrong when running @if($liked)...

Comment: Does `@if(count($liked))` solve things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's ensure your relations are properly set.

***Post model:***

```
public function like() 
{ 
    return $this->HasMany('App\Like'); 
}
```

***Like model***

```
public function user() 
{ 
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id'); 
}
```

***Then combine your two `Post` calls together and run it like so:***

```
$user_id = Auth::id();

$posts = Post::with(['like' => function ($like) use ($user_id) {
    return $like->whereHas('user', function ($user) use ($user_id) {
        $user->where('id', $user_id);
    })->get();
}])->get();

return view('index', compact('posts'));
```

***Then in your view, you can do your check:***

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if(count($post->like))
        ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey this seems to work, but now it's shows on every post that I like them even though I liked only one. Maybe u can explain why ? :)

Comment: I get this `Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause. select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (1, 2) and `user_id` = 2`

Comment: I'm getting "You like this" on every post and I don't clicked "Like" on anyone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116890/discussion-between-labas-gamepage-visogero-and-mike-barwick).